# Using Selenium Webdriver with python/ruby/perl

Tags: python, perl, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to retrieve links programatically that use javascript for their retrieval. For this purpose I have decided to use Selenium which has been suggested by many for this purpose. The machine is command line based linux machine on which I am going to execute has Python2.4 ruby1.8.5 and perl 5.8.8 and I can strictly use the above mentioned versions only for this task in any programming language mentioned. 
Being an absolute beginner I am getting confused with lot of terms with selenium and its compatibility with the above mentioned 'versions' of programming language. I tried reading http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp but was just lost in all those terms related to selenium. Also my purpose in not actually testing my web application. So for my simple purpose of just executing javascripts that retrieve links is there any step by step approach that a beginner like me should know and follow?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [WWW::Selenium](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aSelenium) module?